# Re-use of argument after '@' with argparse's fromfile_prefix_chars='@'

Tags: python, argparse

**Original question:** I am running a python script

> python script.py @runs/run_1/parameters.txt

Is there some way to access the string `runs/run_1` in my script?

**Actual question:** I noticed that what I really need is a little different from the above. Independently from the directory from which I run the script, I need to get the location of `parameters.txt`.

For example, when I'm running the script from the directory `runs/run_1` itself, I still need to get the path. I could do this with `os.getcwd()`.
But when I'm running the code from PyCharm, I pass `@/runs/run_1/parameters.txt` as a parameter, while the script itself lives in some other directory. Here, I would need to read from `sys.argv` as suggested in the comments below.

For now I will have to do differentiate these cases with an if-statement checking whether the string before `parameters.txt` in `python script.py @.../parameters.txt` is empty. Is there a better way?

Comment: "@runs/run_1/parameters.txt" is in the `sys.argv` list at the start of parsing, but is replaced by the contents of the file before any other parsing is done.  In other words this `@` mechanism is quite shallow.  Read the `_read_args_from_files` method for more details.

Comment: I should clarify that that `read` changes the parsers own copy of `sys.argv[1:]`, not the original list.  So that `@` string will still be available after parsing (but test things yourself to be sure).

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, thank you. That works fine for me. I'm reading the run_name from sys.argv and afterwards I do the usual parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj I have to correct myself. The way I originally stated my question didn't quite reflect my usual workflow, so this solution doesn't work. I update the question.